# Regex to match nth occurrence and return subsequent part of string

Tags: regex

I am using Zapier to extract a pattern and I need to use Regex to return a different name for each step of the Zap, from the below data:

'Conversation with Sample Name A (https://www.

“Message from Sample Name A"

Conversation with Sample Name B (https://www.

“Message from Sample Name B”

Conversation with Sample Name C (https://www.

“Message from Sample Name C”

Conversation with Sample Name D (https://www.

“Message from Sample Name D”'

For example for the 3rd Zap I want to return what ever sits between the 3rd instance of 'Conversation with ' and ' (https://www.' which in this case would be `Sample Name C`.

The names will be different each time the Regex is run.

So far I have `^.*Conversation with (\S[^(]*)(?: |\z)`, which returns Sample Name A.

How do I adjust the code to return the 2nd, 3rd or 4th name in the list?

Thanks!

Comment: Then you need to consume the previous part: [`\A(?:^Conv.*\n+){2}`](https://regex101.com/r/ElULJQ/1)

Comment: thanks @bobblebubble, so how would the whole thing look?

Comment: Have you clicked the [link](https://regex101.com/r/ElULJQ/1) (on the pattern) in last comment? It shows the whole thing. Just replace `{2}` with any number of lines before.

Comment: Thanks that works in Regex 101 but returns an error in Zapier Extract Pattern function - any idea why?

Comment: Not really, as I don't know the regex flavor of your tool. Maybe this a bit less accurate one works: `(?:Conv.*\n+){2}Conversation with (\S[^(]*)\b`

Comment: It says: Enter a Python Regular Expression to find the first match for, e.g. f[o]+ (bar)

Comment: Well, then idk because the [first one should be Python compatible](https://regex101.com/r/ElULJQ/2).

Comment: I see why it is happening, because there is other content between the lines in the string. I should have mentioned - the text in the string can vary but will always include the 'Conversation with [NAME] (' pattern. Is there an expression that can return the subsequent part of the string after the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc instances?

Comment: Something like [`(?:Conv[\s\S]*?){2}Conversation with (\S[^(]*)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ElULJQ/3) **without** *global* flag. Replace `{2}` with desired amount of items before.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, we wish to just extract Sample Names, which we can start trying with an expression with a right boundary of `(`, and left boundary is already defined in your original expression:

```
(?:Conversation with )(.+?)(?:\s+\(.+)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tbVSmD/1/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Katie. This returns all the names but I want to return just one name with each piece of code. So for example I only want to return Sample Name C.

Comment: Sorry I will try to be clearer! I can enter a different Regex for each Zap so in the first Zap I want to return what ever sits between the 1st instance of "Conversation with " and " (https://www." Then I need a different Regex to return what ever sits between the 2nd instance of "Conversation with " and " (https://www."

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it like this.
To get the nth one, just put it into the `{nth}` quantifier below.
In this case, we get the 3rd one.

`(?mis)\A(?:.*?^Conversation[ ]+with[ ]+){3}(.*?)(?=[ ]*\(https://)`

https://regex101.com/r/vvT54i/1

Explained

```
 (?mis)                        # Modifiers: multi-line, case-insensitive,  dot-all
 \A                            # Beginning of string
 (?:                           # Cluster group
      .*?                           # minimal, optional any characters
      ^                             # BOL
      Conversation [ ]+          
      with [ ]+ 
 ){3}                          # End cluster, do 3 times
 ( .*? )                       # (1), 3rd Name to capture
 (?= [ ]* \(https:// )         # Assert, https ahead of here
```

Comment: can I return 'Message from Sample Name C' in the same way? I'm looking to find the text between the instances of inverted commas "TEXT"...

Comment: (?mis)\A(?:.*?^\"+){3}(.*?)(?=\")

Comment: @Alan - You mean something like `(?mis)\A(?:.*?^\"Message[ ]+from[ ]+){3}(.*?)(?=\")` https://regex101.com/r/oLqOZf/1 ?